# MySql Same MySql Version Different Server

Tags: mysql

good morning This is my problem

I have two servers

first A: AMD Epyc 7371 - 16c / 32t - 3.1 GHz / 3.8 GHz 256 GB ECC 2400 MHz 2 × 960 GB NVMe SSD MySql 8.0.26

second B: Dual Intel Xeon Gold 6242R - 20c / 40t - 3.1 GHz / 4.1 GHz 384 GB ECC 2933 MHz 6 × 3.84 TB NVMe SSD 2 × 480 GB SATA SSD
On server A, despite being smaller, the database works well and transactions are very fast in terms of users on this server they reach over 200 in councurrency

On the much larger Server B this happens to me: up to 50 concurrent users is not a problem the database works well, after the 50 users to go up, the database starts to slow down.

I specify that both servers have the same database, same tables, same Stored Procedure, same applications, in practice they are a copy of each other
I lost sleep to figure out where the problem lies

---

This is the configuration file

```
[client]

pipe=

socket=MYSQL

port=3306

[mysql] no-beep

default-character-set=

server_type=1

[mysqld]

port=3306

datadir=E:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0\Data

character-set-server=

default-storage-engine=INNODB

sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

log-output=FILE

general-log=0

general_log_file="NS31525947.log"

slow-query-log=1

slow_query_log_file="NS31525947-slow.log"

long_query_time=10

log-error="NS31525947.err"

log-bin="NS31525947-bin"

server-id=1

lower_case_table_names=1

secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads"

max_connections = 500

table_open_cache=3G

tmp_table_size=3G

thread_cache_size=100

myisam_max_sort_file_size=10G

myisam_sort_buffer_size=68G

key_buffer_size=61M

read_buffer_size=23M

read_rnd_buffer_size=256K

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0

innodb_log_buffer_size=512M

innodb_buffer_pool_size=10G

innodb_log_file_size=1G

innodb_thread_concurrency=0

innodb_autoextend_increment=64

innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8

innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000

innodb_old_blocks_time=1000

innodb_stats_on_metadata=0

innodb_file_per_table=1

innodb_checksum_algorithm=0

back_log=80

flush_time=0

join_buffer_size=256K

max_allowed_packet=4M

max_connect_errors=100

open_files_limit=10000

sort_buffer_size=256K

table_definition_cache=1400

binlog_row_event_max_size=8K

sync_relay_log=10000

sync_relay_log_info=10000

loose_mysqlx_port=33060

default_authentication_plugin = mysql_native_password
```

---

I state I also tried to put the same My.ini as server A on server B and nothing i put logs to track write times, and in this case past the 50 users on the B server the writes slow down The strange thing that i noticed that the value of the Key Efficient is always 0.0% unlike Server A the value is 100%

Please Help me Thanks

Comment: Key Efficient is 0% because I don't use MyISAM

Comment: Maybe you can get better answers at dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We're glad you're here. I sympathize with the issue you have described, but it isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow. This site is clear in their [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) that they want questions about specific code problems. You have not included any code example, so this is more of a server tuning and troubleshooting question. Perhaps it belongs on dba.stackexchange.com. But if the problem is actually your code, perhaps it belongs here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The OP has cross-posted to dba.stackexchange.com: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/310254/mysql-same-mysql-version-different-server